# Extract specific value from dataframe if date condition is satisfied

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, specifications

In the following dataframe, I want to run a code to check for today's date in col. D and return specific value from its column A i.e. for 19-06-2020 (today) returns 7 from column A.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame ([[2,3,4], [4,5,6], [7,5,6]], columns = ['A', 'B', 'C'])
df['D'] = pd.date_range(start = '17/06/2020', periods = len(df))
```

[image: df]

Answer (score 0):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with compare today and selecting first matched value:

```
print (df.loc[df.D == pd.Timestamp('now').floor('d'), 'A'].iat[0])
7
```

General solution for select first value with return default value if first valu not exist:

```
print (next(iter(df.loc[df.D == pd.Timestamp('now').floor('d'), 'A']),'no match value'))
7

#for test comapred A column
print (next(iter(df.loc[df.A == pd.Timestamp('now').floor('d'), 'A']),'no match value'))
no match value
```

Comment: Thank you! 

s = df.loc[row condition, column] is used to extract specific value.

next(iter(s)) is used to iterate through the column. What I don't understand is why doesn't the code iterate automatically without using floor('d') ?

Comment: I also see that 
`df.loc[df.A == 7, 'C']`
the above code doesn't need next(iter()) thing to return specific value of 6. It iterates automatically through each row in col. A

Comment: @RajMehta - `s = df.loc[row condition, column]` is used to extract specific value = yes, you are right. But output is Series, it means array with 1, 2 or more values. So `next(iter)` statement is used for selecting first value. it is similar like seelcting first value `.iat[0]`, only better, because  if want seelct non exist value like `df.loc[df.A == pd.Timestamp('now').floor('d'), 'A'].iat[0]` this failed, but `next(iter)` working nice

Comment: @RajMehta - For second is used `floor('d')` with reason `pd.Timestamp('now')` return datetime with actual date but also with actual time. In your data has only dates, with no times. So for possible compare is used `floor('d')` for remove times, so if in your data are datetimes this comparison working nice.